# Should downspouts drain into perforated or solid pipe?

Tags: pipe, drainage

I recently had a contractor re-grade and replace the concrete pad alongside my house, primarily to fix drainage problems. Previously, my downspouts emptied onto cracked concrete where water could seep down alongside my foundation. The contractor dug a trench, laid black corrugated piping, and used T joints to connect the piping directly to my downspouts. The piping slopes down, and empties out through the street curb, where it runs down the block into the city's storm sewer.

At least, in theory. Today I (sadly) emptied a full 55 gallon rain barrel into the end of the drain farthest from the street (about 30 feet), and also sprayed hose water into another opening halfway down, and no water reached the street.

I took a closer look at the piping they used, and it's the perforated variety of corrugated piping, not solid. I can only see the sections right at the downspouts (i.e., right next to my foundation), but I assume that's what was used throughout.

My question is: isn't that wrong? The goal of this piping is not to collect groundwater, and it runs almost entirely under concrete surfaces. I expected solid pipe would be used, to carry water away from the house, towards the storm sewer – at the very least, for the runs connecting the downspouts to the main drain. Some of the water from the downspouts will fall immediately through the perforations in the bottom of the piping.

And if it indeed should be solid pipe, should get it fixed?

Comment: Should be solid at least a few feet(~5 to 10ft) away from foundation.  The perforated pipe should have a sock on it and be in gravel, not just in dirt.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a smart-alec, but I believe you have answered your own questions with the water tests you performed.

Comment: well when you put it like that, @RetiredATC :P – thank you, I think I wanted some reassurance that I understood the situation before I talked to the contractor about it. But yeah, the first 10' of pipe I emptied the barrel into runs alongside my foundation, just a couple of feet away from it. I could hardly ask for a better demonstration of the problem.